# git Best Practice Recommendation

Tags: git

I am looking at setting up git repositories but am coming from a background in SVN.

Here is what I want:

Product Repositories - These capture stand alone individual products (an application, a library for example)

- Application A
- Application B
- Library C
- . . .

Project Repositories - These capture aggregations of products to form a solution for a particular customer.

- Project X repository
- Project Y repository
- Project Z repository
- . . .

Each project will be built up of different combinations of products.  For example, 
Project X is built up of Application A, Application B, and then some project specific code.  Project Y is build up of Application B, Application C, and Application D with project specific code and settings.  You get the idea.

In SVN, the project repositories would use SVN-externals to include a version of the products.

Can I accomplish this with the repository concept I detailed above or should I be thinking of a completely different technique given the power of git?

Comment: This is certainly a useful question (and well-stated), but I do think that [Git Setup Best practices](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9282998/git-setup-best-practices) possibly duplicates it. You may also find [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2732020/899126) useful

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5514739/best-practice-for-git-repositories-with-multiple-projects-in-traditional-n-tier

Answer (score 3):

Consider using Git Submodules. Details can be found in [Submodules chapter of the free online Git book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules). Quoting from the book:

> Submodules allow you to keep a Git repository as a subdirectory of another Git repository. This lets you clone another repository into your project and keep your commits separate.

Answer (score 1):

in my company we ran into the same problem. We solved this be rethinking the way our repositories were structured and used. In particular:

- common code became **shared libraries**
- we started using a **package managment system** (rpm) which allowed to introduce dependences. eg: project X has its own files, but also depends on package A and library C